# SQL (Condition not applied on one column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

this Query have one problem with it , except FOR Column
it show multiple values in this coulmn , put as perthe condition it should only show one value '7' , ddepending on this value the coulmn  value will be set , but now as it show all the value it cuase too much duplication and other issues 
here the query :

```
SELECT        T0.ItemCode, T0.ItemName, T0.CardCode, T0.CodeBars, T0.U_VEN_CODE, T2.UgpCode, T3.AltQty, T3.BaseQty, CASE WHEN T4.Uomentry = - 1 THEN T0.[BuyUnitMsr] ELSE t4.UomName END AS 'UoMName', 
                         T4.UomEntry, T0.U_CAT_CODE, T0.U_CAT_NAME, T1.CardName,
                             (SELECT        TOP (1) PDN1.U_AC_QTY_ORDER
                               FROM            PDN1 INNER JOIN
                                                         OPDN ON PDN1.DocEntry = OPDN.DocEntry
                               WHERE        (PDN1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode) AND (OPDN.CardCode = T0.CardCode)
                               ORDER BY OPDN.DocDate DESC) AS OQuantity,
                             (SELECT        TOP (1) PDN1_1.U_AC_QTY_BONUS
                               FROM            PDN1 AS PDN1_1 INNER JOIN
                                                         OPDN AS OPDN_1 ON PDN1_1.DocEntry = OPDN_1.DocEntry
                               WHERE        (PDN1_1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode) AND (OPDN_1.CardCode = T0.CardCode)
                               ORDER BY OPDN_1.DocDate DESC) AS BQuantity, ITM1_1.Price, T0.U_DISC_PER, SMMU01.WhsCode, SMMU01.OnHand, SMAB01.WhsCode AS Expr1, SMAB01.OnHand AS Expr2, 
                         SMKH01.WhsCode AS Expr3, SMKH01.OnHand AS Expr4, ITM9.PriceList, ITM9.Price AS Expr5, ITM1.PriceList AS Expr6, ITM1.Price AS Expr7
FROM            OITM AS T0 INNER JOIN
                         OCRD AS T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode INNER JOIN
                         OUGP AS T2 ON T0.UgpEntry = T2.UgpEntry INNER JOIN
                         UGP1 AS T3 ON T2.UgpEntry = T3.UgpEntry INNER JOIN
                         OITW AS SMMU01 ON T0.ItemCode = SMMU01.ItemCode INNER JOIN
                         OITW AS SMAB01 ON SMMU01.ItemCode = SMAB01.ItemCode INNER JOIN
                         OITW AS SMKH01 ON SMAB01.ItemCode = SMKH01.ItemCode INNER JOIN
                         ITM9 ON T0.ItemCode = ITM9.ItemCode AND ITM9.PriceList = '7' INNER JOIN
                         ITM1 ON T0.ItemCode = ITM1.ItemCode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         ITM1 AS ITM1_1 ON T0.ItemCode = ITM1_1.ItemCode AND ITM1_1.PriceList = '10' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         OUOM AS T4 ON T3.UomEntry = T4.UomEntry
WHERE        (T0.Series = '65') AND (T4.UomEntry = 3 OR
                         T4.UomEntry = '-1') AND (SMMU01.WhsCode = 'W-SMMU01') AND (SMAB01.WhsCode = 'W-SMAB01') AND (SMKH01.WhsCode = 'W-SMKH01')
```

and here is the result of  the coulmn

```
Expr6
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

how it possiable to let only shown '7' as decided in the condition ?
thx

Comment: can you simplify this a bit to try to isolate the problem, or give us an idea of how the tables relate to eachother? That'd help a lot!

Comment: the problem is in one coulmn whic is (Expr6)  , it should only show one value wich is '7' as per the where condition but insted it read all the values ,  there are some conditions down , i think they aren't work as they suppose too , thx

Comment: try removing     ITM9.PriceList = '7'      from your     inner join     , and put in the     where     statement instead

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  [...]
    , ITM1.PriceList AS Expr6
    , ITM1.Price AS Expr7
FROM   
    OITM AS T0 
    INNER JOIN OCRD AS T1 
        ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode 
    INNER JOIN OUGP AS T2 
        ON T0.UgpEntry = T2.UgpEntry 
    INNER JOIN UGP1 AS T3 
        ON T2.UgpEntry = T3.UgpEntry 
    INNER JOIN OITW AS SMMU01 
        ON T0.ItemCode = SMMU01.ItemCode 
    INNER JOIN OITW AS SMAB01 
        ON SMMU01.ItemCode = SMAB01.ItemCode 
    INNER JOIN OITW AS SMKH01 
        ON SMAB01.ItemCode = SMKH01.ItemCode 
    INNER JOIN ITM9 
        ON T0.ItemCode = ITM9.ItemCode 
        AND ITM9.PriceList = '7' 
    INNER JOIN ITM1 
        ON T0.ItemCode = ITM1.ItemCode 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ITM1 AS ITM1_1 
        ON T0.ItemCode = ITM1_1.ItemCode 
        AND ITM1_1.PriceList = '10' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OUOM AS T4 
        ON T3.UomEntry = T4.UomEntry
```

Your `INNER JOIN ITM1` has not `PriceList = '7'` filter

**You should be able to fix it with :**

```
INNER JOIN ITM1 
    ON T0.ItemCode = ITM1.ItemCode 
    AND ITM1.PriceList = '7'
```

The question is now : why ITM1 and ITM9 are duplicated ?